# How can I send the .xlsx file created on the client to mail?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here I`m creating a file using JQuery plugin table2excel:

```
$('.btn-primary-1').on('click', function(){
    $("#table1").table2excel({
        name:"Worksheet Name",
        filename:"fileName",//do not include extension
        fileext:".xlsx", // file extension
        preserveColors:true
    });
});
```

This is how I fill the table:

```
$('.one_busket').on('click', function(){
    let $tovar1 = $('.title_one').html();
    let $value1 = $('.one_number').val();
    let $itog1 = $('.end1').text();
    $('.tbody1').append('<tr><td class="td_tovar">'+$tovar1+'</td>'+'<td>'+$value1+'</td><td class="td_itog" id="td">'+$itog1+'</td></tr>');
});
```

I can't just send the dynamically created table, so I decided to send an .xlsx file by mail. Now I need not just download the file, but send this file by mail via PHP. How can i do this?

P.S

This is what a crutch looks like now, which can only send 6 goods.

PHP:

```
$input_tovar1 = $_POST['input_tovar1'];
$input_value1 = $_POST['input_value1'];
$input_itog1 = $_POST['input_itog1'];

$input_tovar2 = $_POST['input_tovar2'];
$input_value2 = $_POST['input_value2'];
$input_itog2 = $_POST['input_itog2'];

$input_tovar3 = $_POST['input_tovar3'];
$input_value3 = $_POST['input_value3'];
$input_itog3 = $_POST['input_itog3'];

$input_tovar4 = $_POST['input_tovar4'];
$input_value4 = $_POST['input_value4'];
$input_itog4 = $_POST['input_itog4'];

$input_tovar5 = $_POST['input_tovar5'];
$input_value5 = $_POST['input_value5'];
$input_itog5 = $_POST['input_itog5'];

$input_tovar6 = $_POST['input_tovar6'];
$input_value6 = $_POST['input_value6'];
$input_itog6 = $_POST['input_itog6'];
```

Comment: I'm having hard time understanding you're concern here. So you want to automatically send xlsx file via mail without downloading it first? did I get it right?

Comment: @Shiz, yes. It's just that I'm completely new to development, and I first encountered PHP.

Comment: JavaScript can't access file storage

Comment: can you provide the codes of downloading and sending of mail?

Comment: @Shiz, check P.S in my question.

Comment: PHP runs on the server. If the file is in the browser, first you need to **upload** it to the server. You can use **AJAX** for that. Then you need to generate a mail and attach the uploaded file to the mail as an attachment. I suggest using the PHPMailer library for sending mail with PHP, it will make your life a lot easier than using the standard `mail()` tool.

Comment: P.S. `I am completely new to development`...how new exactly? I would perhaps suggest tackling something a bit simpler if this is your very first piece of work.

Comment: `I'm creating a file using JQuery plugin table2excel` ...why? Even the maintainer of the plugin suggests you to use something else! See https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel (under the section entitled "FIRST!!")